# Buddypress and Headway themes

Tags: wordpress, themes, buddypress

i'm making a website using headway themes and buddypress. I've been watching some videos and all that stuff. I'm using Headway themes 3.1.1 and the problem is; I cant find any "leaf" or cant add theme. Any help would be nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured it out! What you need to do is copy the sidebar.php from bp-default in themes / buddypress. Then you can edit the way you want to. If you dont want any of the buddypress sidebar elemts simply make a blank sidebar.php and place it in /headway/sidebar.php

Hope this helps.